# Why the LogonUser function always return true using the LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK mode?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need to use the [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinApi function on my **Server** App, but this function always returns true no matter if the user and password match or exists. This only happens when the mode passed to the function is `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK`

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows;
var
  hUser : THandle;
  res   : Boolean;
begin
    try
      res := LogonUser(LPWSTR('user'),
                              LPWSTR(nil),
                              LPWSTR('password'),
                              LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
                              LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                              hUser);


    finally
      if hUser>0 then
      CloseHandle(hUser);
    end;
    Writeln(BoolToStr(res, true));
    readln;
end.
```

If I use `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` instead, the function works properly (returns true or false depending of the user and password passed).

Note : I'm using the LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK logon type because the documentation says which is the fastest.

Why the LogonUser function always return true using the LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK mode?

**UPDATE**

The issue occurs in Windows 7 64 bits Ultimate

In Windows  7 32 bits professional works fine.

Comment: Is GetLastError() returning anything interesting after the LogonUser call?

Comment: GetLastError always returns 0.

Comment: Works fine for me. Windows 7 64-bit, Delphi 2009. But it doesn't tell you much since our configurations might be totally different. It sounds like you were having those credentials cached somewhere.

Comment: I'm using XE4 and Windows 7 64 bits too.

Comment: I just tested in another machine with Win 7 32 bits and works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, it seems related to the guest account and the security policies.
First when you uses the `LogonUser` function a New event security is generated. You can check the user account logged in that window.

Check the next image (Invitado=Guest in spanish)

[image]

So in this case no matter which user you uses the *guest user* is used to log on. You can fix this behavior modifying the local security policies, disabling the guest account status.

[image]